# What can I do to stop other people running my Windows RT code?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, obfuscation

Apps downloaded from the Windows Store are installed in this location:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps
```

If you look inside this folder you can access each application's .exe and use reflector to decompile them.

Currently, my Windows RT application sends a password over SSL to a WCF service to ensure that only people using my app can access my database (via the service).

If my code can be read by anybody, how can I ensure that only people using my Windows 8 app are accessing the service?

Thanks!

Comment: Encryption is the answer.  Your application should  have an encrypted key that you encrypt once more before sending accross the network.  But you will still have to generate a unique key for each application the first time that they accesses your service.

Comment: Are client apps and wcf service in the same domain?

Comment: @Casperah, given that the code is accessible, nothing prevents an attacker from reverse-engineering any encryption (you would need to include the key somewhere, ultimately)

Comment: I think, the right way is to establish a Certification Authority and issue unique cert for each user. This way you may restrict access to the database for the user's cert you believe is compromised

Comment: driis is correct, no clever coding on the client side will suffice. Gegor Primar: the client app and wcf service are in separate domains. Serge: detecting a compromised user is almost impossible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the very general sense, it is impossible. If ever you create anything that is placed on the customer's computer, eventually you will stumble upon someone that will manage to decipher your code and understand how to call your service. You may obfuscate it into insane levels, but still it **has to be executable** by the processor, so the processor has to understand it. And if it does, then potentially anyone knowing assembly can understand it too. You may smartly obfuscate it so that it will be very time-consuming to cleanup the code from unimportant trash, but still, at some point of time someone will read it.

One of common defenses is in trying to detect *who** is actually trying to use your service. This is why all the "portals" require you to "register". This way, the application identity is marginalized and it is the user who provides login, password, PGP keys, etc is checked and verified whether he/she is allowed to actually run your service.

Also, on the OS/framework layer, there are several ways to selectively provide "licenses" to your customers and then in your application you may use keys/hashes from the licenses to authenticate in your service. This may partially remove from the user the burden of remebering the passwords etc, or it may provide an additional authentication factor, or it may simply be a yes-no flag that allows to run the app or not. Still, it will not guard your code against being read. Licenses just help in verifying if the software copy is legit and if belongs to that specific user/computer.

You may act selectively only against 'reflectoring' (or dotpeeking, or ildasming, or ...). Those tools really make the decompilation easy (although the original reflector is now paid software). So, the simpliest form would be to use obfuscator that will make the decompilation impossible or harder - that cuts some percentage of the potential code-readers and you can assume scriptkiddies are gone. You may ignore obfuscators and you may write the service connector in **native** code (C++, not C++/cli). That will make the code completely un-reflectorable and un-ildasmable, and that will cut off another large percentage of people, but with some will still be left (me and thousands of others, but that's much less than millions).

While this does not give you definitive answer, I wanted to show you that you can only get some "level of hardness", but you cannot make it totally safe from being read. This is why you should focus on making the service access in that way, that showing your code to a stranger on the street does not compromise your security.

Now gettint to your problem: the core thing seems to lie not in the fact that your app uses some secret algorithms, but rather - that you have hardcoded the password in. You see, there's with this approach, they do not need to read your code at all. They just need to listen what data your app sends over the sockets..

Another issue is that **everyone uses the same keyphrase**.

A hardcoded magic string may be some sort of validation, but never authentication. If you want the app to be register-free, make the registration silent and automatic at first run? Of course, you will just bounce the problem: anyone could read the code and learn how to autoregister, and then they will make a clone.. But, again, like I've said: you never know who's on the other side. Is it your app, or is it an ideal-clone of it? Or maybe is it a clone that uses your own hacked-a-bit libraries to connect to you? If it looks like a duck, and quacks like a duck, it is a duck..

Comment: Good (but saddening) answer. Hardcoding a password is never the answer. I imagine I could do it by user login and authenticating entirely on the server. If I used LiveIDs for instance and did sanity checks on the query requests I should be able to prevent misuse and of course, the code would be stranger on the street safe. Also, as I'm using SSL, they shouldn't be able to see what is being transmitted... right?

Comment: yes/yes/yes/then no. SSL does not protect from that. When person A sends data to person B, the SSL allows both of them to be mostly sure that A is really A and B is really B, and that no other C will read the packets without intercepting A's and B's private keys. It does NOT however protect A from reading his own packets.. At your own computer you can always install some hook at socket level or network card level and simply listen to what parameters are being passed to SEND method. And there at some offset will be your magicstring, which will be later encrypted and send over the wire..

Comment: It of course needs at least "some" level of expertise and it is not as easy as starting the reflector, but could guess that the tools to locally listen on your own SSL packets are lying on the internet, too. Maybe even Wireshark can? Never tried though.